# When clicked on a menuitem, show another menuitem

Tags: java, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I've been trying to set one of the two booleans (Distribution and Zwaluw) true when a one of the companies is chosen.Obviously that works like this, but once the company is chosen it should set another JMenu visible.

**This is the code which sets the boolean true**

```
  menuItem = new JMenuItem("Bedrijf..");
              menu.add(menuItem);
              menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                        Frame frame2 = new JFrame("Kies het juiste programma");
                        String keuze = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame2, "Programma", "Kies het juiste bedrijf", 
                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, bedrijven, bedrijven[0]);
                        if(keuze.equals(bedrijven[0])) {
                            Distribution = true;
                        }
                        if(keuze.equals(bedrijven[1])) {
                            Zwaluw = true;
                        }
                  }
              });
```

**This is the code which should be executed once a company is chosen**

```
 menu = new JMenu("Aanmaningen");
              menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
              menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                      "Debiteuren aanmanen");
              menuBar.add(menu);
              menu.addSeparator();
              ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
              if(Distribution) {
                  rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Aanmaningen automatisch verzenden");

                  rbMenuItem.setSelected(false);
                  rbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                  group2.add(rbMenuItem);
                  menu.add(rbMenuItem);
                  rbMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        chosenComp = true;
                        f.getContentPane().add(new Main());
                          f.revalidate();
                          f.repaint();
                             Distrscherm obj = new Distrscherm();
                             obj.plannerJTable();
                    }

                  });
              }
```

Obviously you don't really know the methods i use here etc, but I think this is more like a general question. 
So what would come to my mind is:

1. a while loop which is always true (but I think that is pretty broken lol)
2. calling a method INSIDE the first code that runs the second code (so when button called, do the method in code2)
3. Using f.revalidate() and .repaint -> doesn't work

However, I've tried 2 and since menu isn't final, I can't pass it to the other method. Tried multiple options, didn't show the menuitem.

Any idea's on how to do this? :)

Comment: Let me see if I've understood what you want.  The user will click on the menu item "Bedrijf..", which will pop up a dialog on which the user makes a selection of either "Distribution" or "Zwaluw". The item labeled "Aanmaningen automatisch verzenden" on the "Aanmaningen"  menu will then be either visible or invisible depending on which choice the user made.  Is that more or less correct?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yep that's exactly correct :)

Comment: I believe, then, you should be thinking in exactly those terms of "visible" or "not visible".  Add the "Aanmaningen ..." item to the "Aanmaningen" menu but make it initially not visible (`rbMenuItem.setVisible(false);`).  In the action listener for the "Bedrijf.." item, use `rbMenuItem.setVisible(true);` when you want to make the  "Aanmaningen ..." item visible, and `rbMenuItem.setVisible(false);` when you want to hide it.

Comment: Ah nevermind this will actually still be impossible because "bedrijf..." and "aanmaningen" are different sections in the menu and therefore, I'm not able to use rbMenuItem within "Bedrijf..." Also, just a little update: I changed it to a menuItem instead of rbMenuItem. .setvisible is not applicable for menuitem

Comment: You might need to move the declaration of `rbMenuItem` to a point where it will be visible to your action listener.

Comment: Yes I think I have to add this whole menuItem to the actionlistener of Bedrijf... But honestly? I think it should be possible way easier.. It seems so broken lol

Comment: Not the whole `rbMenuItem = ...` statement!  That can stay where it is.  I mean the actual `MenuItem rbMenuItem` _declaration_, which is somewhere outside of the code you've shown.  If that declaration is buried inside of a method, moving it up to class level could help (unless you've got the menu-creation code split across a bunch of classes, of course...)

Comment: In that case I will face the error that the items MAY not have been initialized

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mafBaJLn this is that whole method.. So maybe you get what I mean

Comment: You'll want to have `JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Aanmaningen...");` outside of the `menu()` method; all the rest of the setup for that menu item can stay inside.